# How could we avoid while wrongly double tapped a button to move to wrong activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have Three activities A,B and C. I have two buttons back to back in B and C in the same position as shown in the below images. When I tap button in Activity C it should go to Activity B and when I click Activity B it should go to Activity A. When I wrongly tap Activity C twice with a small time delay, it directly move to Activity A. How could we avoid this kind of scenario? [image]

[image]

Comment: pressing one time is working fine ?

Comment: the screenshots are useless here... **:/** ,anyway, where is the screen shot for Activity A...  **:P**

Comment: @Darkie. While pressing one time is working fine.

Comment: The reason is both the buttons are on the same postion of the screen; on your second click the consumer of the touch event is the button of activity **B** rather than the **C** (which you are thinking),and there you have wriiten the code of jumping to the Activity **A**

Comment: +1 for @nobalG, ShankarManickavasagam if you want to make sure, just set a different text for the button in B, or the background color of B then you will find out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd note the time when activity B resumes and ignore clicks on the back button until some amount of time has passed.  It could probably be really short, maybe 250-500 ms.  You don't want to interfere with deliberate double presses.